# Java Textbox - converting byte to String

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I have a java application where you enter a String into a textbox, hit encrypt, and it will show the encrypted String in a seperate textbox. I will be using AES encyption for this. The problem is that I cannot get the crypted text to show as it is in byte but the textbox wont show byte (only takes String). Below is an exert from my code.

```
 public static byte[] encrypt(String plainText, String encryptionKey) throws Exception {
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));
return cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
}

private class HandleThat implements ActionListener{
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eve){
 JTextField jtf; //user will enter string here
 JTextField jtf1; //this will show the encrypted text
 plaintext = jtf.getText();
 String error = "Error, you must provide some text"; 
        if(eve.getActionCommand().equals("Encrypt")){
            if(!jtf.getText().equals("")){
             try{   
             byte[] cipher = encrypt(plaintext, encryptionKey);
             for (int i=0; i<cipher.length; i++)

             jtf1.setText(cipher[i]); //here is where I get my error
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();}
        }else{
                label.setText(error);
        }
        }
```

Error - "method setText in class JTextComponent cannot be applied to given types;
  required: String
  found: byte
  reason: actual argument byte cannot be converted to String by method invocation    conversion"

How can I change cipher from byte to String?

Comment: Would you like to decode the bytes to the characters?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html — There is a constructor `String(byte[] bytes)` which will do that.

Comment: Use [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/). They hold vast knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to [pretty-print](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prettyprint) the array of `byte` values use:

`Arrays.toString(cipher)`

If you want the cipher to be interpreted as a `String`, use:

`new String(cipher)`

Comment: Just curious, but what exactly do you mean by 'pretty-print'?

Comment: @MojaveStorm If you have `byte[]{23, 41, 41, 15}` the output of `Arrays.toString()` will be a string `[23, 41, 41, 15]`.  It's pre-formatted for display.

Comment: The Arrays.toString(cipher) worked perfectly. I was missing the Arrarys aspect which is why it failed when I tried the conversion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A typical format to show bytes and byte arrays is hexadecimal display. For example, many ciphering applications show the keys in hexadecimal format.

You can use the method shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855338/671988) to convert `byte[]`  to `String` in hexadecimal format.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't built-in to the API because generally cipher-text contains non-printable characters.  You may want to encode the encrypted text as [Base-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), especially if the user plans to do something with it (like send it in an email).  This will ensure that all characters are printable.